# Why am I able to see all of the database's passwords when visiting a page of my web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web-applications, socket.io

I am currently using app.get and app.post for input and output from my database. This works perfectly fine, but when I go to the /login page for my web application, I am able to see all of the data for all of the players in a large array. I tried this on multiple computers, and it seems that anyone can view it. Is there any way to make app.get and app.post pages unreachable?

**My code snippet:**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  var query = { username: req.body.username };
  
  dbo.collection("data").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if(result.length == 0){
      var myobj = { username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password };
      dbo.collection("data").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {});
    }
    res.send(result);

  });
    
});
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  dbo.collection("data").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(result);
  });

});
```

I am using mongodb's serverless instance, and node.js to run the code.

**On the /login page(example.com/login):**
[image: This is an example of what I see when I go to the /login page of my website.]
The passwords were changed for privacy sake.

Comment: PS... (Just as a sanity check) You're aware that passwords should be salted, encrypted, etc... are you?

Comment: You're using `res.send(result);` instead of `res.sendFile`. What do you expect?

Comment: You are literally querying the database and just sending the results to the client. What's unexpected about that?

Comment: i mean you are returing every data in your database hence ```.find({})``` what did you expect. Also take note of what Roko said I would suggest you use something like ```bcrypt ``` to encrypt your passwords

Comment: First of, on login GET, just sendFile a login page. On login POST check if the email exists in database, then check the email match (use i.e: Node's bcrypt for that!) authenticate the user, save a Cookie with expiration date and user ID into your database, respond with a Set-Cookie header, and send the user to some welcome or index page. Learn how to securely store passwords. Use an ExpressJS middleware to secure all your pages (using Cookie header) that need the user to be authenticated... etc etc

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments! I will look at bcrypt and encrypt the passwords. If the passwords are encrypted, I don't think it really matters if anyone can access it.. does it? I feel like you only need one of them, either encryption or required authentication. I'll try to do them, thanks!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am using mongodb, which isn't really a file. How would I use sendFile to access it?

Answer (score 0):

With everyone's comments, I was able to figure out how to fix it!

The way to fix the problem, is to use app.post() functions to transfer data from the index.html file to the index.js file. This allows everything to be done behind the scenes. With this information, I was able to only res.send() a boolean instead of the entire array. This made it so that the page only showed "true" or "false" instead of everyone's data. Furthermore, I used bcrypt to encrypt passwords, so even if hackers could see the data, they could not hack anyone.

Comment: Please format your answer and references as well to clarify.